# Как проверить Андроид на безопасность?

Tags: java, android

Как можно проверить что телефон а именно Android (6.0) + не содержит троянов, есть ли алгоритмы для этого ? надо внедрить в свой проект или open source антивирус какйто откуда мжно взять куски кода

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки устройств на наличие троянов создаются огромные приложения. Это не самый простой процесс. Советую Вам погуглить и Вы точно найдёте то, что Вам будет по силам реализовать. Например, мне показалось, что [данная реализация](https://github.com/Sanjeet990/Android-Antivirus-Project) хоть и очень медленная, но довольно легко реализуемая.
Перед тем, как ответить на Ваш вопрос я покапался в нескольких открытых исходниках антивирусников и сделал вывод, что в каждом примере есть свои плюсы и минусы:

- Где-то необходим сервер
- Где-то очень сложная реализация
- Где-то очень медленная скорость сканирования

В Вашем случае советую присмотреться к исходникам выше.